# Issues pointing a sub-domain at an Apache 2 virtual host?

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm having a little trouble getting this to work. Right now the DNS is propagating for my domain, so I have just been using the regular IP address, if this makes a difference.

In my `/etc/hosts` file I have the following...

```
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
111.111.111.11 main.mydomain.com  main
111.111.111.11 git.mydomain.com
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

I have only added one line to this file, that line being `111.111.111.11 git.mydomain.com`. The rest was there when I got this VPS.

I've also created this Apache config file `git.conf` and added it to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName git.localhost
        ServerAdmin allen@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/allen/Sites/Git
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is simply a copy of the `000-default.conf` file that Apache uses by default, with the comments removed and with some information changed.

I have run the command `sudo a2ensite git.conf` as well as restarted the Apache server.

The goal here is to serve a virtual host that has a web client for managing Git repositories when the sub-domain is `git`.

Have I made any mistakes in the config file? Is there a step that I am missing in order to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the apache conf file you may need to change the line

> ServerName git.localhost

to

> ServerName git.mydomain.com

I'd also take a look at this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html